# GORM nil error when fetching data from postgres

Tags: postgresql, grails-orm

I'm trying to fetch one to many table data from my postgres DB using GORM but I keep getting the following error when I attempt to print the returned data

```
&{0xc00015e3f0 <nil> 1 0xc000272e00 0}
```

I have verified that the data exists in my db and here is the code showing how I've structured everything

```
type User struct {

    
    gorm.Model
    Name         string 
    Email         string    
    Password  string    
    Documents []Document
    
    
}

type Document struct {
    
    gorm.Model
    Name         string 
    DateCreated         string  
    UserID uint 
    
    
}

func GetAll(db *gorm.DB) ([]*models.User,) {
    var users []*models.User
   //err := db.Model(&models.User{}).Preload("Documents").Find(&users).Error
    results:=db.Preload("Documents").Find(&users)
    fmt.Println(results)
    fmt.Println("got users")
    return users
}

func main (){
    models.Db.Create(&models.User{Name: "Ellie",Email: "Ellie@lous",
    Documents: []models.Document{{Name:"Ellies ID",},{Name: "Ellies Guitar "}},


})

GetAll(models.Db)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that the data from your query will scan into `users`, not `results`.

Try this:

```
_ = db.Preload("Documents").Find(&users)
for _, user := range users {
    fmt.Println(user)
}
```

The `Find` function returns a `*gorm.DB` object, not the results of your query.